# Custom browser preferences for file download

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, preferences

While using Selenium WebDriver as web automation framework, I have a question - 
how can I configure Google Chrome and Internet Explorer to save downloaded files to specific (not default) folder and also without showing additional "save file" windows.

Webdriver has a FirefoxProfile for Mozilla Firefox browser, but what about other browsers?

Example for Firefox :

```
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

        profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);

        profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);

        profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", "\\Somedir\");

        profile.SetPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);

        profile.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);

        profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip, application/x-gzip");
```

Answer (score 1):

With Chrome, it can be done, it is just not as easy and straightforward as Firefox profile manipulation is.

Since the WebDriver bindings expose the ability to add in 'custom' abilities and command line parameters, you can give it any of the command line switches that Chrome knows about:

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

With this, we can give Chrome a profile to load, just as you do with Firefox.

However the WebDriver bindings don't expose the options as well as the Firefox profiles. So it has to be done manually.

Firstly, find out where your profiles live:

Go to this URL in Chrome.

```
chrome://version/
```

It will tell you what profile it's currently loading (and what command switches it is using). Copy the Profile Path into Explorer and go to it.

It should be, by default, using the `Default` profile directory. Go up on level in explorer, so you sit in the `User Data` folder.

Next step, create a new profile for Selenium to use. Open Chrome, go to Settings > Users > Add a new user. Give it a name.

Once created, Chrome will open up a new Chrome window for that user. Next step is to force Chrome, for this user only, to save downloads in a certain place.

This can be done either two ways. In the Chrome UI, go to the Settings, and change the download directory and ensure the checkbox next to it is unchecked, or to get a little more **creative...**

All Chrome preferences are stored in a file, stored in the users directory. You should have an explorer window open already, sitting at the `User Data` folder in Chrome's user folder. You should hopefully see it's created a new profile (probably called `Profile 1`). Go into it.

Now look for a file called **Preferences** (no extension).

Edit it with Notepad (it's a text document, with JSON).

Look for the download section, it will look like this:

```
"download": {
    "directory_upgrade": true,
    "extensions_to_open": ""
},
```

Add in this key, putting in the path you want to save your files to:

```
"default_directory": "PATH",
```

Make sure you escape any slashes in the path, with another backslash, in the same way it is escaped when you use the Visual Studio debugger.

For instance, `C:\Bob\Jim\Downloads` should be input as `C:\\Bob\\Jim\\Downloads`.

Save this file.

Now you have a profile where the downloads go to a certain place. How to make Chrome use this profile? You tell it which profile to open up at launch. The command line would be:

```
--profile-directory="Profile 1"
```

(Replace `Profile 1` with whatever it is called in the `User Data` folder, if it isn't called that).

OK, we can tell Chrome to load up a particular profile, but how do we tell Selenium to do this too? Easy! Add it in as an 'additional command line switch'.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument(@"--profile-directory=""Profile 1""");
```

Selenium will take care on ensuring that command line switch is passed down to Chrome.

(Note: if anyone knows of an easier solution, let me know!).

As for IE, I have tested this on IE8 and IE9 and it works OK. IE can take into consideration a registry key for where the default downloads location is. I cannot comment on IE7 or below though.

Navigate to, using **regedit** to (it is a **per Windows user** settings):

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer**

Add in a string value called `Download Directory`. It's **value** will be the exact location of where you want the downloads to go. No need to escape the path BTW.

Simply ensure the user you are logged into under Windows has set this value, and there will be no more setup needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code for chrome. Even I'm looking for a similar option for IE.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
String downloadFilepath = "/path/to/download";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOptions("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--test-type");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```